Getting InvalidAuthenticationToken error while making microsoft graph api request
I need to get the list of all the files in one drive using a nodejs api. I have registered an app on azure and have implemented the code flow for authentication as described here :-
OneDrive authentication and sign-in
By completing this flow, I am getting a response like :-
{ token_type: 'Bearer', scope: 'onedrive.readwrite Files.ReadWrite', expires_in: 3600, ext_expires_in: 3600, access_token: 'EwBIA61DBAAUTiVFeGt35mbkQxMI9wgOQmfZjKAAAZOEQOoKIIDONUpQLPCcmj5sM1oecOJkK8...', refresh_token: 'M.C545_BAY.0.U...' }
But when I try to use the access token I received in above response, I am getting the following error:-
{ "error": { "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken", "message": "IDX14100: JWT is not well formed, there are no dots (.).\nThe token needs to be in JWS or JWE Compact Serialization Format. (JWS): 'EncodedHeader.EncodedPayload.EncodedSignature'. (JWE): 'EncodedProtectedHeader.EncodedEncryptedKey.EncodedInitializationVector.EncodedCiphertext.EncodedAuthenticationTag'.", "innerError": { "date": "2024-06-30T13:46:22", "request-id": "2498d892-c5f5-41ee-8883-ac67c3533e46", "client-request-id": "2498d892-c5f5-41ee-8883-ac67c3533e46" } } }
This is the api request I am trying:-
curl --location --request GET 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v2.0/me' \ --header 'Authorization: Bearer EwBIA61DBAAUTiVFeGt35mbkQxMI9wgOQmfZjKAAAZOEQOoKIIDON...'
The answer in this forum suggests it's due to expiration of the access token.
I tried getting a new access token using the refresh token, but the issue did not resolve.

Have you tried pasting your JWT token into a debugger to see if the one you're using is valid? A valid JWT token string should const of three parts separated with a dot as following: header.payload.signature

@MikeDoe The same token that is received from the authentication flow is being sent in the request, but the access token that is received is not in that format. But the documentation on the given link says that we are supposed to use the same access token directly in the authorization header


Note that: According this MsDoc, for OneDrive authentication and sign-in for personal accounts, you need to make use of Microsoft Graph and authorize and sign-in for OneDrive in Microsoft Graph only.

Create a Microsoft Entra ID application and grant API permissions:


Make use of https://login.microsoftonline.com

Generated auth-code:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=files.readwrite offline_access
&state=12345


Generated tokens:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token

grant_type:authorization_code
client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:files.readwrite offline_access
code:Code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms


I used this token to call the API and it is successful:
curl --location --request GET 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer EwBYA8l6BAAUbDba3x2OMJElkF7gJ4z/VbCPEz0AAdtv9Wz9KVEmRot'


The error usually occurs if you are passing invalid token format or invalid URL.
To resolve the issue, check the below:

Make sure the token you are passing does not contain extra spaces or characters or words while calling the API.
The URL you are making use of https://graph.microsoft.com/v2.0/me is not valid. You need to call v1.0 endpoint that is https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me API.

To do the same in node.js, make use of below code and make sure to pass access token without any space or extra characters.
const axios = require('axios');
async function listFiles(accessToken) {
    const config = {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` }
    };
 
    try {
        const response = await axios.get('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children', config);
        console.log(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.response ? error.response.data : error.message);
    }
}
const accessToken = 'EwBYA8l6BAAUbDba3x2OMJElkF7gJ4z/VbCPEz0AAdtv9Wz9KVEmRo...';
 
// List files in OneDrive
listFiles(accessToken);

I am able to successfully call OneDrive API:

I got the same error, when the word "Bearer " is taken along with the access token:
const accessToken = 'Bearer EwBYA8l6BAAUbDba3x2OMJElkF7gJ4z/VbCPEz0AAdtv9Wz9KVEmRo...';



Not sure how you're using /common as the tenant. When I created an application to target personal onedrive accounts I had to use /consumers and the API told me as much. But for whatever reason, going through your process with /consumers and even though the token is not a proper JWT, the graph API /v1.0/me continues to say the authorization header is not a well formed JWT.

Please post a new question with all the details and paste the link here will help you:)
